# Displaying responsive website on mobile devices exactly the same as on desktops

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a problem with following website

www.tylkomarkowa.pl

Basically it's responsive (BS 3.0), but with loads of custom queries. I would like to remove all reponsiveness from this site, but it's difficult. So I wonder if there is any way to force mobile devices to show full site, so it looks just like on desktops, without div stacking etc.

I've tried already viewport width=1200 and higher but it doesn't work at all. I would like to have 1200px container on mobiles, even if horizontal scrolling is necessary. Any idea? Thank you. I'm stuck. I've tried also fixing width on container but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove responsiveness from the design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Firstly, removing responsiveness from the website is a terrible idea. It will drastically impact SEO like you've never seen before, as a Google update coming April 21st will take how mobile-friendly your website is *very seriously*.

Now that I've made that point, I'll show you a few steps you can take to remove this feature.

Firstly, from any webkit browser, open the debugging console, then go to the **sources** tab. From there, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to allow you to search through all of the source file. Type "**@media**", and it will list you all the occasions of `@media query {}` - this is where all the responsive magic happens.

I've added a screenshot so you can see the result. From here you can see there are 327 occurrences. This will take a long time to get rid of, but this is your first step to making the site a mobile headache.

Then, like your intuition told you, you must keep the viewport wide. This seems to be as simple as changing your `min-width: 240px` to `min-width: 1200px` in `global.css` on line **6689**.

This should be all or most of the work ahead of you to fuck up your mobile visitors' experience :) Hope it helps!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should remove all the

```
position:absolute;top:....
```

Like things or try to design with simple HTML and CSS to get work on all devices

Comment: I bought this template. My business partner just doesn't want any responsive features. He wants his site to look on mobiles exactly as on desktops. I have very big problem because of that ;( Any ideas?

Comment: @luka5z So.. You may have to re-design ur website... Vote up my answer.plz..... :)

Comment: @luka5z i would not recommend removing responsive features, for SEO purposes. You will get more hits if the site is responsive. Tell that to your business partner :) Also RaviPrakash, this is not the correct answer as it would not make the site less responsive, you would have to remove all media queries

Comment: @RaviPrakash, the question was how to remove all responsiveness, with your answer you would destroy the desktop version of the site aswell. He wants mobiles to display the desktop version of the site, not the have their own version of it.

Comment: @Slugge.   He should choose any one feature..... Else, Can't remove responsive design..

Comment: exactly that is the point Slugge. I would like to make Desktop version the only version. So there is no resposibility whatsover. I thought that if I fix viewport "view" to 1440 or so, website on mobile would look exactly like on dekstop with 1440px resolutions. But why it doesnt work? Let's skip SEO, philosophy itd. I know it's not the right thing to do, but decision is already made.

Comment: @luka5z do you have any media queries in your css file? I see you mentioned you do, so the only way to make it non-resposive is to remove all of them and all the code in them

Comment: But its very very complicated. And some of them look like that: min-width:900{} etc. so i cant just delete any of them. Really no way to force viewport size or sth so it wont trigger responsive rules?

Comment: @luka5z. Not really easy.

Comment: Im sorry, but thats the only way :)